# vcard export download in Codeigniter works only once

Tags: php, codeigniter, vcf-vcard

I want my user to select multiple contacts and export their details in vcard format.This is my controller:

```
function get_contacts_email_vcard()
            {
                $this->load->library('vcard');                
                $datavcard = $this->getvcard($this->user_model->get_email_contacts());
            } 

            function getvcard($dat)
            {
                $datavcarddata = array();
                foreach($dat as $data){
                $datavcarddata['display_name'] = $data->name;                                                 
                $datavcarddata['cell_tel'] = $data->mobile_no;                
                $datavcarddata['email1'] = $data->email;   
                if (is_array($datavcarddata))
                {    
                    $this->vcard->vcard($datavcarddata);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->vcard->vcard();
                }
                $this->vcard->zipdownload();
                }
                return $datavcarddata;
            }
```

This is my view:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>auth/get_contacts_email_vcard">vCard(Address Book)</a></li>
```

This is my model:

```
$this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('contacts');
            $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->order_by('date_created', 'DESC');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
```

The issue I am  facing is that this works only once. Only the data of the last contact from my database gets downloaded in a zip file. I want to create different zip files or vcf files for different contacts. And i also want to create a single zip file containing all the vcf files.

Comment: I don't know how the vcard library works, but if looks like it's the culprit. Does it have any methods that return the vcard data so you can put it in an array and zip up all the cards together?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure. I tried creating an array and zipping it , but it didn't work.

Comment: I have used this library: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/vCard-Library

Comment: Anyone out there who can resolve my issue :-(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After plenty of research I have found that a single click event(or any other event) can only send one download request to the browser. So it is impossible to download multiple vcards

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tblname');
$info = $this->db->get()->result();
$userContacts = new stdClass();
$userContacts->data = $info;

$dataArray = '';

foreach($userContacts as $contact)
{

      for($i=0; $i<sizeof($contact);$i++)
      {


        $first_name = $contact[$i]->name;

        $last_name = '';

        $mobile_number = $contact[$i]->mobile;

        $email_address= '';

        $dataArray .="BEGIN:VCARD\nN:$first_name;$last_name\nFN:$first_name\nTEL;TYPE=WORK,MSG:$mobile_number\nEMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:$email_address\nEND:VCARD\n";

      }

    }


   $data = $dataArray;

   $size = strlen($data);

   $filename = "Restaurants.vcf";

   header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

   header("Content-Length: $size");

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```